# Is there a cross repository access token available in GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

Scenario:
Create an issue in `org/bar` whenever an action gets triggered by a PR in `org/foo`.
I've used the organization's private key to create a token to request `https://api.github.com/repos/org/bar/issues` for creating the issue, but the problem is if the PR is from a fork, the action can't access `org/foo`'s secrets. So it means the action can't ready the private key from the secrets to create the access token.

The access limit description in the documentation: https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow

So, since `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have access to other repositories in the organization, is there any other possible way to do the authorization for creating an issue on another repository using a GitHub action?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the same approach as I did in [Workaround to post comments from GitHub actions from forked repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419552/workaround-to-post-comments-from-github-actions-from-forked-repos/61450807#61450807) :

- create a cron job to regularly check for some condition (i.e. PR is created), and if condition is met, execute steps that require elevated privileges.
- a PR could create some artifacts that cron job could use. Just make sure cron job is reasonably secure to not be manipulated into doing something evil.